# Delegate is logging non-public events through my app: can those events be detected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

These notices are being logged on behalf of my app (which implements GKSessionDelegate), and I could *really* make use of these events to help users with connection difficulties. Is there any way I can detect them? There aren't any public instance methods for the delegate that directly refer to these events.

I'm hoping there's some sort of generic event catch-all for delegates that I could rig up.

```
GKSessionTester[79766:307] BTM: attaching to BTServer
GKSessionTester[79766:307] <<< Session >>> +[GKBluetoothSupport _determineBluetoothStatus]: BT not available - try again later.
GKSessionTester[79766:307] BTM: posting notification BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification
```

Comment: You should rephrase your question title to focus on detecting GKSession events *or* capturing log messages. Those are two radically different approaches to your problem. (If you want to cover both cases, ask two separate questions.)

Comment: Rather than asking about GKSession, I'm trying to keep it about delegates/events in general, since it's probably not a GKSession-specific problem.

Comment: Reading the logs looks like a potential solution; I'll edit this to more specifically ask about events. Thanks, Benjamin.

Comment: As the log mentions, BTServer is posting a notification called BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification. Why don't you suscribe to this, and any other notification interesting to your app instead of reading and parsing the logs?

Comment: It doesn't seem like BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification is a public method. I can't find any reference for BTServer, either.

Comment: I've confirmed that BluetoothManager is a private framework, as is GameKitServices. Those two frameworks are the sources of those log messages, and it looks like they're being used by GameKit.

So the question remains: can I put an observer on them, or otherwise trigger a method call when those events fire?

Answer (score 1):

As [Gonzalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225589/gonzalo-larralde) mentions in the comments, it looks like a notification is being posted with the name `BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification`.

Cocoa's notifications system is based around NSNotificationCenter, which maintains a list of observers and forwards notifications based on names, which are simply NSStrings. It is very likely that you can receive notifications if you call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(bluetoothAvailabilityChanged:)
    name:@"BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification"
    object:nil];
```

And implement the method:

```
- (void)bluetoothAvailabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // maybe [notification userInfo] has some useful info...
}
```

You might not receive any notifications if GameKit is using a separate notification center object.

Does this count as private API? I would say it's no worse than parsing your console output. You are not calling methods on undocumented classes, you are passively observing notifications posted with a given name.

Of course, Apple's opinion is the only one that matters. If I were in your shoes, I would make sure that:

1. your app functions correctly if the notification is never posted (because a future iOS might not post it, or you might have to remove the code and resubmit without it);
2. your app makes no assumptions about the NSNotification's `object` or contents of its `userInfo` dictionary (because whatever they contain today might change in the future).

Alternatively, you could figure out a way to intercept your own app's STDOUT and STDERR (any solution that works on generic UNIX may work on iOS) and watch the text for relevant log messages.